# Select Tags when parsing XML with NSXML Parser Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have my parsing xml working but I want to pick up One value and actually my parser read and write them all in an NSDictionnary

Let me show you

The xml i am talking about : [XML](http://www.logaviv.com/xml/Euronext%20Ma%C3%AFs.xml)

As you can see, the main Tag is "marche", there is 7 Tags "echeance". In each  tag we have the 10 last dates and each "date" contains several values.

Actually, I want to get those values and ONLY those values :

- For EACH "echeance", pick up the the attibute "nom" for the tags "echeance" AND "settle" and variation of the most recent date (For each echeance).

This is what i got as result :

```
2012-03-02 20:04:08.576 XML[4497:f803] stories :(
    {
    echeance = "Mars 2012\n    ";
    settle = "205.25\n      205.5\n      206\n      205\n      202.75\n      204\n      204.75\n      206.5\n      206.25\n      210\n      ";
    variation = "-0.25\n    \n    -0.5\n    \n    1\n    \n    2.25\n    \n    -1.25\n    \n    -0.75\n    \n    -1.75\n    \n    0.25\n    \n    -3.75\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Juin 2012\n    ";
    settle = "207.75\n      207.5\n      207.25\n      206\n      204.75\n      205.5\n      206.25\n      207.25\n      206.5\n      210.5\n      ";
    variation = "0.25\n    \n    0.25\n    \n    1.25\n    \n    1.25\n    \n    -0.75\n    \n    -0.75\n    \n    -1\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    -4\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Ao\U00fbt 2012\n    ";
    settle = "209.75\n      209.25\n      208.5\n      207.25\n      205.75\n      207.25\n      207.75\n      208.75\n      208.5\n      211.75\n      ";
    variation = "0.5\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    1.25\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    -1.5\n    \n    -0.5\n    \n    -1\n    \n    0.25\n    \n    -3.25\n    \n    0.25\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Novembre 2012\n    ";
    settle = "188.25\n      188\n      186.75\n      186.25\n      184.75\n      184.75\n      186.5\n      186\n      185\n      188.5\n      ";
    variation = "0.25\n    \n    1.25\n    \n    0.5\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    0\n    \n    -1.75\n    \n    0.5\n    \n    1\n    \n    -3.5\n    \n    1\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Janvier 2013\n    ";
    settle = "189.75\n      189\n      189.5\n      188.75\n      187.25\n      187.25\n      188.5\n      188.5\n      187.5\n      190\n      ";
    variation = "0.75\n    \n    -0.5\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    0\n    \n    -1.25\n    \n    0\n    \n    1\n    \n    -2.5\n    \n    0\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Mars 2013\n    ";
    settle = "191\n      191\n      191.5\n      190.75\n      189.25\n      189.25\n      190.5\n      190.5\n      189.5\n      192\n      ";
    variation = "0\n    \n    -0.5\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    0\n    \n    -1.25\n    \n    0\n    \n    1\n    \n    -2.5\n    \n    1\n    \n    ";
},
    {
    echeance = "Juin 2013\n    ";
    settle = "194.5\n      194.5\n      195.5\n      194.75\n      193.25\n      193.25\n      194.5\n      194.5\n      193.5\n      196\n      ";
    variation = "0\n    \n    -1\n    \n    0.75\n    \n    1.5\n    \n    0\n    \n    -1.25\n    \n    0\n    \n    1\n    \n    -2.5\n    \n    3\n    \n    ";
}
```

)

As you can see i have a beautiful NSDictionnary "stories" with each "nom" of "echeance BUT for "settle" and "variation", i have the values for ALL the dates for each "echeance" and not ONLY THE MOST RECENT.

If my parser would work, i should have something like that  :

```
2012-03-02 20:04:08.576 XML[4497:f803] stories :(
    {
    echeance = "Mars 2012";
    settle = "205.25"
    variation = "-0.25"
},
    {
    echeance = "Juin 2012";
    settle = "207.75"
    variation = "0.25"
```

.....
.....
.....
ETC ...

Here is my code :

**My .m model :**

```
    #import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize stories;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL*)path 

{
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    textParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path];

    [textParser setDelegate:self];

    [textParser parse];

}


- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError 

{
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Impossible de parser le document (Code erreur %i )", [parseError code]];

    NSLog(@"erreur de parsing XML: %@", errorString);

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur lors du chargement" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlert show];
    [errorAlert release];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if(currentElement)
    {
        [currentElement release];
        currentElement = nil;
    }
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kExpiry]) 

    {

        if(item)
        {
            [item release];
            item = nil;
        }
        if(currentExpiry)
        {
            [currentExpiry release];
            currentExpiry = nil;
        }
        if(currentSettle)
        {   
            [currentSettle release];
            currentSettle = nil;
        }
        if(currentVariation)
        {
            [currentVariation release];
            currentVariation = nil;
        }

        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentVariation = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSettle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentExpiry = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"nom"]];


    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kExpiry]) 

    {
        [item setObject:currentExpiry forKey:kExpiry];
        [item setObject:currentSettle forKey:kCloture];
        [item setObject:currentVariation forKey:kChange];

        [stories addObject:item];

    }   
    //NSLog(@"compteur : %i",compteur);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{

    // on sauve les éléments de l' echeancepour l'item en cours
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:kCloture])
        [currentSettle appendString:string];
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:kExpiry])
        [currentExpiry appendString:string];
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:kChange])
        [currentVariation appendString:string];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 

{

    NSLog(@"C’est fini !");
    NSLog(@"stories a %d echeances", [stories count]);
    NSLog(@"stories :%@", stories);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(tellTheDelegateItIsFinished) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) tellTheDelegateItIsFinished {
    [delegate xmlParserdidFinishParsing];   
}

- (void) dealloc 

{
    [stories release];
    [textParser release];
    [item release];
    [currentVariation release];
    [currentExpiry release];
    [currentSettle release];

    [super dealloc];

}
@end
```

I guess i need to "count" and pick up only the value i need but it does not work

The other problem i have, is the "\n". I am not able to avoid those "\n" :( But the main problem is the picking up of the "good values" ;)

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem might be that you're not stopping the parse in your didEndElement implementation. You have a line `if ([elementName isEqualToString:kExpiry])` so that's why you only get one date. But you don't do that for the "settle" and the "variation" so you get all of them. You add them to the dictionary and you add the dictionary to the array but those are just pointers, so data keeps coming in and it keeps getting added to them - inside the dictionary inside the array.

Comment: Hmmm ok ! What do you suggest to me ! (i am sorry, i am a beginner in the world of progrmation)

Comment: Well, I would never have structured the program the way you have. I would design actual objects to fit the nature of the data, and I would parse the whole XML into those objects. I'd have a Marche class and an Echeance class and a Date class and a Graphe class and I'd parse the whole XML hierarchically into a structure to match the structure of the XML. And I wouldn't try to parse the XML with a single delegate as you're doing; I'd use the multiple-delegate strategy: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingMultipleDelegates.html